# What's the usage for openDynamicLinkAction with example

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I'm working on the Gmail addon with alternative runtime using nodejs. There is an option openDynamicLinkAction and the documentation says

https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/reference/rpc/google.apps.card.v1

"An add-on triggers this action when the action needs to open a link. This differs from the openLink above in that this needs to talk to server to get the link. Thus some preparation work is required for web client to do before the open link action response comes back."

And nowhere mentions how the response structure should be to execute open link as a popup using openDynamicLinkAction.

Please help me with the proper usage of this option.